# Add watermark to animated GIF with imageMagick (PHP)

Tags: php, imagemagick, gif, imagick

I need add watermark to animated GIF with imageMagick .
But i have a problem !
**My Code :**

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("orginal.gif");

$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("watermark.png");

// how big are the images?
$iWidth = $image->getImageWidth();
$iHeight = $image->getImageHeight();
$wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
$wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();

if ($iHeight < $wHeight || $iWidth < $wWidth) {
// resize the watermark
$watermark->scaleImage($iWidth, $iHeight);

// get new size
$wWidth = $watermark->getImageWidth();
$wHeight = $watermark->getImageHeight();
}

// calculate the position
$x = ($iWidth - $wWidth) / 2;
$y = ($iHeight - $wHeight) / 2;

$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y);

header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
?>
```

**Original GIF :**
[See Original GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l70lj.gif)
**Output GIF :**
[See Output GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1XbG.gif)

My GIF is not animated after creating the watermark !
How can i fix it ?

Comment: You need to coalesce the images and apply the watermark to each frame then re-assemble http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php

Answer (score 1):

You have just found some code to watermark an image. With an animation you need to separate each frame, watermark it and put it back together. Check out: [coalesce](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.coalesceimages.php)

Answer (score 0):

A simple example on how to do it:

```
$watermark       = new Imagick( 'watermark.png' );
$image           = new Imagick( 'original.gif' );
$iWidth          = $image->getImageWidth();
$iHeight         = $image->getImageHeight();
$x               = ( $iWidth / 2 );
$y               = ( $iHeight / 2 );
$image_coalesced = $image->coalesceImages();

do {

   $image_coalesced->compositeImage( $watermark, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x, $y );

} while ( $image_coalesced->nextImage() );

$image_coalesced->writeImages( 'output.gif', true );
```